# jQuery Sum show NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, onkeyup

On keyup on price, I am calculating the total price of (quantity * unit price) individual products and at the end I have field which will auto generate the grand total of all individual totals. I was able to auto calculate the individual totals but I am stuck on the grand total. It shows NaN. How can I fix it ?

code:

```
$('.prc').on('keydown keyup', function(){
    // total_array = [];
    flag = $(this).attr('flag');
    prc = $(this).val();
    qntty = $('.qntty_'+flag).val();
    mul = prc * qntty;

    total = 0;

    total = total + parseFloat($('.total_'+flag).val(mul));

    $('#total').val(total);

})
```

Comment: [`.val(mul)`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) return jQuery object which casted to `NaN` when summing

Comment: so how should i fix it ?

Comment: When setting the value with `val` it doesn't return a value, it returns the jQuery object. You can't set the value and return it at the same time.

Comment: @WahidSherief You have to set input's value separately from summing: `$('.total_'+flag).val(mul); total = total + parseFloat(mul);`

Comment: Something like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/bc9vajpc/), note that the `total` variable is useless, zero plus a number makes no sense, and you're basically setting the value for both the two elements at the bottom to the same thing

Comment: it helps .. but it doesnt sum up all the total values and just update great total field with current mul @adeneo

Answer (score 0):

How silly me or i genius i am .. very angry with myself .. cz I solved it magically adding few code. Added a class 'e' in all total classes and run an each operation, get the value and added them to make a sum. Happy at last.

working code :

```
        $('.prc').on('keydown keyup', function(){

            var sum = 0;
            flag = $(this).attr('flag');
            prc = $(this).val();
            qntty = $('.qntty_'+flag).val();
            mul = parseFloat(prc) * parseFloat(qntty);

            $('.total_'+flag).val(mul);

            $('.e').each(function(){
                sum += +$(this).val()
            })

            $('#total').val(sum);
        })
```